# control default browser with c# (get content from webpage and fill input fields)

Tags: c#

i have loged in to my web page using my default browser,if i can control default browser then no need to log in to the web page again and again,please help me to fix this issue,Thank you!

Comment: what do you want ? :)

Comment: i want to control web bages ( click , get contents )

Comment: If you want to run some tests I think you should look at web automation tools, like Selenium... ?

Comment: got it :) thank you !